# Save to / update existing file in Content folder in MVC 5?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have a .json file in my Content folder that needs to be read from and written to. Both functionalities work great in my local site, but when I push it to production, only reading from works and writing gives me a 500 error.

Is there anyway to save to or update an existing file in the Content folder of a live production site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in development, IIS Express runs as your user and has permissions to whatever your user account does. In production IIS (or specifically, the AppPool) runs as IIS_USR, by default, and only has permissions assigned to that user.

For security, IIS_USR only has read and/or execute privileges in the document root. Normally, web site files being allowed to be modified by the web server would be a *bad* thing. If you need to allow this, then you need to give IIS_USR (or whatever other user the AppPool impersonates) write access to the Content directory.

However, it should be noted that the files in the Content directory are not intended to be modified. At the very least, republishing the site could very well overwrite or otherwise destroy any modification you've made. At the worst, you may be opening up a vector of attack. I would suggest confining your writes to a directory outside of the document root of your site, and then if you need to access the files from there, you can add a virtual directory.

Comment: Thank you very much. (I had no idea Chris Pratt was a web dev, what can the man not do?!) But you make some very great points - I'm going to do just that. Thanks again!